# Codeigniter resizing of image not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, image-resizing

I am trying to resize the uploaded image to height of 163px maintaining aspect ratio and then upload it to a folder. I tried with the following code:

```
$id=1;     // user id
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['upload_path'] = './userdata/'.$id;
$config['height'] = '163px';
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
//$config['master_dim'] = 'height';
$config['source_image'] = $filename;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
{               
     echo $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

However this is uploading the image to the correct folder but the image is not resized. I uploaded an image of size *170*128* and it is uploaded to folder as it is without resizing. What is wrong with my code?

Can anyone help me to find the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the height need to be in px? Or can you just use '163'?

Comment: it should be `$config['height'] = '163';` remove `px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this cleaner version, the config for height or width doesn't need a px, hence your code is a little bit confusing :

```
$id = 1;

$config = array(
    'upload_path'   => './userdata/'.$id,
    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
    'encrypt_name'  => true,
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$field_name = "file"; // change this with your file upload part's field name if different

if ($this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
    $image = $this->upload->data();
    $config = array(
        'image_library'   => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $image['full_path'],
        'maintain_ratio'  => true,
        'height'  => 163,
     );
     $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
     if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
     }
     $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

Comment: i've tried this in my local and its working, can you check if the gd is installed or enabled with a simple phpinfo() call?

Comment: @Burak..I got it working. The problem was I included `$this->load->library('image_lib')` multiple times..

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple...

You have to do one thing Go to Captcha_helper.php and search

instead of

```
    $x = mt_rand(0, $img_width / ($length / 3));
```

Do Like this

```
    $x = mt_rand(0, $img_width / ($length / 1));
```